# Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: infrastructure

Now that this has been released, I'm starting to look into upgrading my sharepoint servers. (plus everything else too i guess too)

http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/downloads/pages/windows_7_sp1.aspx

Has anyone installed the RTM yet?

Did anyone install the beta and see any problems?

I normally have automatic updates turned off, does anyone have a neat little script to install the patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no known problems with SharePoint 2010 and Service Pack 1 for Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Installed the SP for Win2k8 R2 -no problems so far.